# Django 4.1.9 requires_system_checks issue with manage.py - is this a bug or not

Tags: python, django

Django 4.1.9 requires_system_checks issue with manage.py - is this a bug or not

we are upgrading our wagtail 4.2.2 app to from django 3.1.9 to django 4.1.9

getting the error

```
TypeError: requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple.

when running 

python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8020 --keep-meta-shutdown
```

Is this a bug and / or can i be worked around

Could I monkey patch BaseCommand.**init**() to set requires_system_checks = []

Comment: Do you use `django-bower` by any chance (directly or indirectly). This is the result of Django updating some logic: https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower/pull/84#issuecomment-1554746977

Comment: no we dont use that library

Comment: Well likely it is a similar issue, but perhaps a different class. You should change the `False` to the empty tuple.

Comment: but we are not setting requires_system_check this is the core manage.py runserver command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 4.1, support for setting a boolean to `requires_system_checks` on a management command was dropped ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#features-removed-in-4-1)).

You'll need to check your django "app" dependencies to see which define management commands, and which could be affected. Here's some examples, but the list is not exhaustive:

- graphene-django fixed in 3.0.0 (technically, [fixed in 3.0.0b8](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/releases/tag/v3.0.0b8))
- django-extensions (noted by @DavidU) [fixed in 3.2.1](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/releases/tag/3.2.1)

Answer (score 4):

Resolved issue by upgrading dependancy django-extensions to latest version 3.2.1